# Nginx Pagespeed нестабильные показатели

Tags: nginx, pagespeed-insights

Существует сервер, на нём связка nginx -> apache -> fastcgi-php. Nginx скомпилирован с последним модулем pagespeed (ngx_pagespeed 1.12.34.2-0).

На сервере крутится несколько сайтов, для всех хочется использовать Pagespeed.

Суть в том, что очень часто оптимизированные ресурсы пропадают со страниц сайтов, заходишь в тестирование Pagespeed Insights выдаёт красные цифры (30-50), ждешь минуту, ресурсы обрабатываются, тестируешь снова, получаешь зелёные 95. Потом, спустя 5-10 минут история повторяется, будто оптимизированные ресурсы вычищается с сервера или кэш перезаписывается другими сайтами.

В nginx.conf добавляются вот такие настройки pagespeed:

```
pagespeed ListOutstandingUrlsOnError on;
pagespeed ProcessScriptVariables on;
pagespeed FetchWithGzip on;
pagespeed RewriteLevel CoreFilters;
pagespeed RespectVary off;
pagespeed DisableRewriteOnNoTransform off;
pagespeed InPlaceResourceOptimization off;
pagespeed SupportNoScriptEnabled false;
#pagespeed ModifyCachingHeaders on;
pagespeed MaxCacheableContentLength -1;
pagespeed FileCachePath /var/cache/pagespeed;
pagespeed FileCacheSizeKb            10485760;
pagespeed FileCacheCleanIntervalMs   360000000;
pagespeed FileCacheInodeLimit        50000000;
pagespeed LRUCacheKbPerProcess     1024;
pagespeed LRUCacheByteLimit        16384;
pagespeed ImageMaxRewritesAtOnce -1;
pagespeed RateLimitBackgroundFetches off;


## PageSpeed admin pages configuration
pagespeed UsePerVhostStatistics on;
pagespeed Statistics on;
pagespeed StatisticsLogging on;
pagespeed StatisticsLoggingIntervalMs 60000;
pagespeed StatisticsLoggingMaxFileSizeKb 1024;
pagespeed MessageBufferSize 100000;
pagespeed LogDir /var/log/pagespeed;
pagespeed StatisticsPath /ngx_pagespeed_statistics;
pagespeed GlobalStatisticsPath /ngx_pagespeed_global_statistics;
pagespeed MessagesPath /ngx_pagespeed_message;
pagespeed ConsolePath /pagespeed_console;
pagespeed AdminPath /pagespeed_admin;
pagespeed GlobalAdminPath /pagespeed_global_admin;

## PageSpeed Cache Purge
pagespeed EnableCachePurge on;
pagespeed PurgeMethod PURGE;
pagespeed DownstreamCacheRewrittenPercentageThreshold 95;

## PageSpeed configurations
pagespeed FetchHttps enable,allow_self_signed,allow_unknown_certificate_authority;
```

В каждый блок serve виртуальных хостов nginx добавляются вот такие настройки:

```
pagespeed on;
#pagespeed NoTransformOptimizedImages on;
## Resource filters
## Text / HTML
pagespeed EnableFilters combine_heads;
pagespeed EnableFilters collapse_whitespace;
pagespeed EnableFilters convert_meta_tags;
pagespeed EnableFilters elide_attributes;
pagespeed EnableFilters pedantic;
pagespeed EnableFilters remove_comments;
pagespeed EnableFilters remove_quotes;
pagespeed EnableFilters trim_urls;

## JavaScript
pagespeed EnableFilters combine_javascript;
pagespeed EnableFilters canonicalize_javascript_libraries;
pagespeed EnableFilters inline_javascript;

## CSS
pagespeed EnableFilters outline_css;
pagespeed EnableFilters combine_css;
pagespeed EnableFilters inline_import_to_link;
pagespeed EnableFilters inline_css;
pagespeed EnableFilters inline_google_font_css;
pagespeed EnableFilters move_css_above_scripts;
pagespeed EnableFilters move_css_to_head;
pagespeed EnableFilters prioritize_critical_css;
pagespeed EnableFilters rewrite_css;
pagespeed EnableFilters fallback_rewrite_css_urls;
pagespeed EnableFilters rewrite_style_attributes_with_url;

## Images
#pagespeed EnableFilters dedup_inlined_images;
#pagespeed EnableFilters inline_preview_images;
pagespeed EnableFilters resize_mobile_images;
#pagespeed EnableFilters lazyload_images;
pagespeed EnableFilters convert_gif_to_png;
pagespeed EnableFilters convert_jpeg_to_progressive;
pagespeed EnableFilters recompress_jpeg;
pagespeed EnableFilters recompress_png;
pagespeed EnableFilters recompress_webp;
pagespeed EnableFilters strip_image_color_profile;
pagespeed EnableFilters strip_image_meta_data;
pagespeed EnableFilters jpeg_subsampling;
pagespeed EnableFilters convert_png_to_jpeg;
pagespeed EnableFilters resize_images;
pagespeed EnableFilters resize_rendered_image_dimensions;
pagespeed EnableFilters convert_jpeg_to_webp;
pagespeed EnableFilters convert_to_webp_lossless;
pagespeed EnableFilters insert_image_dimensions;
pagespeed EnableFilters make_google_analytics_async;

pagespeed DisableFilters inline_images;
pagespeed DisableFilters sprite_images;

## Miscellaneous
pagespeed EnableFilters add_instrumentation;
pagespeed EnableFilters insert_dns_prefetch;

## Cache
pagespeed EnableFilters extend_cache;
pagespeed EnableFilters extend_cache_pdfs;
pagespeed EnableFilters local_storage_cache;


pagespeed Disallow "*/bitrix/js/*";
pagespeed Disallow "*/bitrix/css/*";


pagespeed JpegRecompressionQuality 85;
pagespeed ImageRecompressionQuality 85;

## Ensure requests for pagespeed optimized resources go to the pagespeed handler
## and no extraneous headers get set.
location ~ "\.pagespeed\.([a-z]\.)?[a-z]{2}\.[^.]{10}\.[^.]+" {
  add_header "" "";
}

location ~ "^/pagespeed_static/" { }
location ~ "^/ngx_pagespeed_beacon$ps_dollar" { }

## PageSpeed Admin paths
## PageSpeed Admin UI paths
location /ngx_pagespeed_statistics {
  auth_basic "Restricted";
  auth_basic_user_file key/.htpasswd-users;
}
location /ngx_pagespeed_global_statistics {
  auth_basic "Restricted";
  auth_basic_user_file key/.htpasswd-users;
}
location /ngx_pagespeed_message {
  auth_basic "Restricted";
  auth_basic_user_file key/.htpasswd-users;
}
location /pagespeed_console {
  auth_basic "Restricted";
  auth_basic_user_file key/.htpasswd-users;
}
location ~ ^/pagespeed_admin {
  auth_basic "Restricted";
  auth_basic_user_file key/.htpasswd-users;
}
location ~ ^/pagespeed_global_admin {
  auth_basic "Restricted";
  auth_basic_user_file key/.htpasswd-users;
}
```

Как видно, размер и таймауты кэша достаточно большие, модуль включается для каждого виртуального хоста; пробовал глобально включать в nginx.conf, та же история.

Добавлю, что сайты работают как с https так и по http, для https добавляется:

```
pagespeed LoadFromFile
```

Comment: мне кажется надо сделать нагрузочное тестирование через apache ab. проверить логи и выяснить в чем причина.